# How to display fetch result on table view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsdictionary, contacts

I want to display the data which is fetched now display on tableview checkout my code

```
- (void) fetchContacts
{

    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted == YES) {
            //keys with fetching properties
            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
            NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
            } else {
                NSString *phone;
                NSString *fullName;
                NSString *firstName;
                NSString *lastName;
                UIImage *profileImage;
                NSMutableArray *contactNumbersArray;
                for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                    // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
                    firstName = contact.givenName;
                    lastName = contact.familyName;
                    if (lastName == nil) {
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
                    }else if (firstName == nil){
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
                    }
                    else{
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
                    }
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
                    if (image != nil) {
                        profileImage = image;
                    }else{
                        profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person-icon.png"];
                    }
                    for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
                        phone = [label.value stringValue];
                        if ([phone length] > 0) {
                            [contactNumbersArray addObject:phone];
                        }
                    }
                    NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: fullName,@"fullName",profileImage,@"userImage",phone,@"PhoneNumbers", nil];
                    [_Contacts  addObject:personDict];

                    NSLog(@"%@",phone);
                    NSLog(@"%@",fullName);
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self.contacttableview reloadData];



                });
            }
        }
    }];

}




- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.Contacts count];



}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [_contacttableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];







        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@" person-icon.png"];
        cell.imageView.image = image;

    }


   cell.textLabel.text = [_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

from this code name and phone number of person is coming on console but not able to dislay on a tableview.

Now i want in the place of text label name of person is come and in the detail label text its phone number is come

and in the cell image its contact picture will be come whatever he stored on his iPhone

Comment: Did you init _Contacts like this: _Contacts = [NSMutableArray array];

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the Contacts array if not initialised.

As i see you are adding dictionary to array. From array you can fetch the objects like:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"fullName"];

cell.imageView.image = [[self.Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"userImage"];
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of fetching you have stored NSDictionary objects on self.contacts array.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [_contacttableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    //get person dictionary first    
    NSDictionary* personDict = [_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

   //get person image from dictionary and assign to cell.image.
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[personDict objectForKey@"userImage"]];
   cell.imageView.image = image;

   //get person name from dictionary and assign to cell.fullname.
   cell.textLabel.text = [personDict objectForKey@"fullName"];

   //There is no extra label on default UITableview cell, so you can add your description as bellow with same text label or you can use CustomCell
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",[personDict objectForKey@"fullName"],[personDict objectForKey@"PhoneNumbers"]];

    return cell;
}
```

**NOTE:** Please prepare custom cell if you don't want to show Fullname and Phonenumber in one default UITableviewcell textlabel.

Comment: the row method which i write a code for that its right or wrong

Comment: Yes. Your row method code is right. on [_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] you will get NSDictionary object not a fulsome directly. You can check in fetch contacts function code where you added NSDictionary object on _contacts array like this - [_Contacts  addObject:personDict];........ From NSDictionary object you will get fullname, phone number and userImage.

Comment: can you plz illustrate with custom cell

Comment: Hi Ravi. here is the example http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: yes i have tried that example in my project but when complier come to that line  
        
        
    if(cell == nil){
    
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    
    }     
its give exception n signal sigbart and start crashing

Answer (score 0):

Are u using custom cell r normal cell.
use custom cell u will get

and check the json format  try with this cutsom cells

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString * cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

```
UITableViewCell * cell=[self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

UITextField * text=(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

NSLog(@"%@",text);

return  cell;
```

}

Comment: srry i m using normal cell thats why

Comment: can you plz illustrate with custom cell

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath,

```
NSDictionary* personDict = [_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [personDict objectForKey:@"fullName"]
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [personDict objectForKey:@"PhoneNumbers"]
cell.imageView.image = userImage;
```